# How to change rendered font of the navigator

Tags: html, css

I'm using ATOM and i tried to change the font family from google fonts of the body in my code but for something doesn't change.

First i doing this: href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

Comment: can you finish your description?

Answer (score 0):

ok theres like a couple of ways to import google fonts

1:
in html>head

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

then in css

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

2:

in css file

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');

then

then in css

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```